# How to store sysdate in variable with formate as 25Jan2014

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

How to store sysdate in formate as 25Jan2014, I am able to capture date in formate as
25012014 with below mention query

```
@echo off
SetLocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('') do set year=%%c
for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /T') do set month=%%a
for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /T') do set day=%%b
set TODAY=%day%%month%%year%
echo %TODAY%
```

How to capture date in 25Jan2014 formate?

Comment: be aware that the line that determines your year is missing the 'date /T' statement.

Answer (score 2):

This is a way to achieve what you want

```
@echo off
SetLocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /T') do set year=%%c
for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /T') do set month=%%a
for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /T') do set day=%%b

if %month%=01 set monthname=Jan
if %month%=02 set monthname=Feb
if %month%=03 set monthname=Mrt
if %month%=04 set monthname=Apr
if %month%=05 set monthname=May
if %month%=06 set monthname=Jun
if %month%=07 set monthname=Jul
if %month%=08 set monthname=Aug
if %month%=09 set monthname=Sep
if %month%=10 set monthname=Oct
if %month%=11 set monthname=Nov
if %month%=12 set monthname=Dec

set TODAY=%day%%monthname%%year%
echo %TODAY%
```

Beaware that this solution only works if the date is represented with `/` on my box the delimiter is `-`

Comment: Can you help me with complete query. I have very basic knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

The Batch file below solve your particular problem:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set m=100
for %%a in (Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec) do (
   set /A m+=1
   set month[!m:~-2!]=%%a
)
for /F "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /T') do set TODAY=%%b!month[%%a]!%%c
echo %TODAY%
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if you modify your script to give the proper format, it is locale dependent, meaning it may not work on all machines, depending on how they are configured.

The solution is trivial if you use [getTimeStamp.bat - a hybrid JScript/batch utility that performs date and time computations and formatting](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4847). The utility is pure script that runs on any modern Windows machine from XP onward. Full documentation is embedded within the script.

Assuming you have getTimeStamp.bat in your current directory, or better yet, somewhere in your path:

```
call getTimeStamp -f {dd}{mth}{yyyy} -r TODAY
```

The utility defaults to English month abbreviations, but there is an option available to specify the abbreviations for any desired language. There are also options for full month name, day of week name, and day of week abbreviation.

Answer (score 0):

## Potential issues

Parsing either the `%date%` variable or the `date /t` output is not reliable because:

1. The date/time format is not the same for all locales.
2. The format can be further customized.

## Alternate solution

Use `wmic` instead. Type this command to see all available date/time values:

```
wmic path Win32_LocalTime get /all /value /format:list
```

### Example script

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set months="Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec"

call :getDate
call :getMonthName %month%

set TODAY=%day%%monthName%%year%
echo %TODAY%
exit /b

:getDate
for /f "skip=1 tokens=1-3" %%A in ('wmic path Win32_LocalTime get day^,month^,year /value /format:table') do (
set day=00%%A
set day=!day:~-2!
set month=00%%B
set month=!month:~-2!
set year=%%C
exit /b
)

:getMonthName
for /f "tokens=%1" %%A in (%months%) do (set "monthName=%%A")
exit /b
```

## References

- [GetDate | SS64.com](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-getdate.html)